# Grouping and counting across documents?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection with documents similar to the following format:

```
{
  departure:{name: "abe"},
  arrival:{name: "tom"}
},
{
  departure:{name: "bob"},
  arrival:{name: "abe"}
}
```

And to get output like so:

```
{ 
  name: "abe",
  departureCount: 1,
  arrivalCount: 1
},
{
  name: "bob",
  departureCount: 1,
  arrivalCount: 0
},
{
  name: "tom",
  departureCount: 0,
  arrivalCount: 1
}
```

I'm able to get the counts individually by doing a query for the specific data like so:

```
db.sched.aggregate([
  {
    "$group":{
      _id: "$departure.name",
      departureCount: {$sum: 1}
    }
  }
])
```

But I haven't figured out how to merge the `arrival` and `departure` name into one document along with counts for both.  Any suggestions on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a `$map` to split your doc into 2, then `$unwind` and `$group`..

```
[
{
    $project: {
        dep: '$departure.name',
        arr: '$arrival.name'

    }
},

{
    $project: {
        f: {
            $map: {
                input: {
                    $literal: ['dep', 'arr']
                },
                as: 'el',
                in : {
                    type: '$$el',
                    name: {
                        $cond: [{
                            $eq: ['$$el', 'dep']
                        }, '$dep', '$arr']
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
},

{
    $unwind: '$f'
}, {
    $group: {
        _id: {
            'name': '$f.name'
        },
        departureCount: {
            $sum: {
                $cond: [{
                    $eq: ['$f.type', 'dep']
                }, 1, 0]
            }
        },
        arrivalCount: {
            $sum: {
                $cond: [{
                    $eq: ['$f.type', 'arr']
                }, 1, 0]
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    $project: {
        _id: 0,
        name: '$_id.name',
        departureCount: 1,
        arrivalCount: 1
    }
}
]
```

Comment: Wow - that's giant.  I might just do it as two separate queries.  Is there a benefit to doing it this way vs two queries?

Comment: Just looks huge, blame the JS linter :) You plan to merge them in memory?

Comment: It's actually going to end up in a new collection, so I was going to run once to insert departures and then another to update with the arrivals

Comment: You still are sending a lot of data over the network.

Comment: Actually parallel queries would be better here for performance, though it would be utililzing "two" connections instead of one, and arguably sends "less traffic" in the request than a longer pipeline. Of course this is a "merge" and depends more on the data output size. Nice try though. You are overusing `$project` stages ( bad thing as each is a physical pass through data ) though, and it should not be hard to work out the first two stages can be one. Another MongoDB 3.2 optimization is `"f": [{ "type": "dep", "name": "$departure.name" },{ "type": "arr", "name": "$arrival.name" }]]`